How to automate Pseudo Scrollbar using Selenium Java, which is not present in DOM
I'm trying to automate a Scrollbar using Selenium, which is not present in DOM. I see the Styles related to the scrollbar. I'm unsure of how to automate it. Can anyone please let me know how to scroll that Scrollbar.
I'm using Selenium with Java to automate this.
Attaching the Image of Styles of Scrollbar.
pseudo-scrollbar-image
Although I see the solutions related to this, I'm unsure of what values to pass in this method.
document.querySelector(element, pseudoElement).click() since there is no element for this in DOM.
